# Flow exception, but flow is not visible in setup

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

I encounter Flow error when trying to Insert record in test class:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow. A flow trigger failed to execute the flow with version ID 3010E000000CpxD. Flow error messages: **An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow**
> An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow.  Please contact your system administrator for more information.  Contact your administrator for help.: []

I wanted to add fault message, so I can see what is the deal, but its not displayed in setup in flows tab and I can't add in process builder either. 
I managed to view it in Flow Designer. But I still can't find where it's invoked from.

I haven't worked much with flows, so maybe it's a silly question, but why I can't see it in setup? To my knowledge there is no Record Sharing for flows.

**UPDATE**

Here is the not accessible flow

[image: Here is the invisible flow]

Here are visible flows

[image]

And here is list of processes in Process builder (I sorted by type and there is no Contact)

[image]

Interesting part is that I was able to find this flow in process builder in another related org.

Comment: Check for what flows you have in `Setup > Create > Workflow & Approvals > Process Builder`. I imagine this is where the error is being generated.

Comment: Thanks for response, @DanJones.
Well, I have a questions then. Does Process builder internally converts its processes to flows?
I also thought so, but I haven't found any processes on given SObject

Comment: The Process Builder is the same as a Workflow, only where as Workflow can be thought of as an `if/then` flow, Process Builder is an `if/then if/then if/ then if/ then` type flow. It may not need to Trigger anything on the given sObject, rather something that the sObject is related to. At least, potentially.

Comment: Thanks @DanJones. I was talking about VisualWorkflows and to my understanding VisualWorkflows can be more compelecated then simple `if/then`.

Comment: @ytiq Go to **Create > Workflow & Approvals > Flows**

Comment: @Reshma, as I said this flow is not displayed in setup. That's my question. Why this is happening

Comment: ytiq, as @DanJones mentioned, this `Flow` is used by `Process Builder`. You can access it by opening for edit any existing Flow in you or and replacing Id with `3010E000000CpxD`, however I'm not recommending editing it as it's being managed by Process.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This article from the Salesforce Knowlegebase may help: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231232&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: If the linked article answers the question, please cite the relevant portion here.

Comment: The relevant portion is the entire article, which is too long to paste here.

Comment: The linked article now gives a 404 error.  That's why you might want to cite at least a sentence or two

Answer (score 0):

Check your user detail page. You should be Force.com flow user.
[image]

Or else 'Run flows' permission should be enabled for your profile. Go to your profile. Under system permissions find 'Run flows'.
[image]

If you want to add fault message.

[image]

Comment: thanks I am System Administrator. I checked this permissions - they do not affect System Administrator permissions (I checked them, but still can't see this flow).

Comment: Can you add screenshot where you can't see flows.